# Class conforming to Codable protocol fails with encodeWithCoder: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, nskeyedarchiver

I know that there are several questions similar to this, that tend to all revolve around the class not conforming to the protocol properly, but that should not be the immediate issue here.

The following is a condensed version of the code that is currently giving me this problem:

```
enum Binary: Int {
    case a = 0
    case b = 1
    case c = 9
}

final class MyClass: NSCoder {
    var string: String?
    var date: Date?
    var binary: Binary = .c

    override init() { }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case string, date, binary
    }
}

extension MyClass: Codable {
    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        string = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .string)
        date = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        binary = try Binary(rawValue: values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .binary)) ?? .c
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(string, forKey: .string)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
        try container.encode(binary.rawValue, forKey: .binary)
    }
}
```

I have created the following class which then attempts to call `MyClass` with the purpose of writing & reading it to `UserDefaults`:

```
class MyClassController {
    private let myClass: MyClass

    init() {
        self.myClass = MyClass()
        self.myClass.string = "string"
        self.myClass.date = Date()
        self.myClass.binary = .a
    }

    func writeMyClass() {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myClass)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: String(describing: MyClass.self))
    }

    func readMyClass() {
        if let decoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: String(describing: MyClass.self)) as? Data,
            let myClass = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded as Data) as? MyClass {
            print("string: \(myClass.string ?? "nil") date: \(myClass.date ?? Date()) binary: \(myClass.binary)")
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I call the writeMyClass function though, I get this error:

> [DemoDecoder.MyClass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance #blahblah#

Two things I have also tried:

- Adding `func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` to `MyClass`
- Removed all properties from `MyClass` & `CodingKeys` and the init/encode functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a lot of mismatched attempts and various encoding/decoding mechanisms.

`NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` require that all involved types conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. This is the older mechanism from the Objective-C frameworks.

The protocols `Codable`, `Encoder`, and `Decoder` are new to Swift 4. Such data types should be used with Swift encoder and decoders such as `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` or `PropertyListEncoder` and `PropertyListDecoder`.

I suggest you remove the reference to `NSCoder` and remove the uses of `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Since you have implemented the `Codable` protocol, use an appropriate Swift encoder and decoder. In your case you want to use `PropertyListEncoder` and `PropertyListDecoder`.

Once that is done you should probably change `MyClass` to be a `struct` instead of a `class`.

You should also avoid use `UserDefaults` to store data. Write the encoded data to a plist file instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have not worked with these in years and got mixed up with the new protocols & old approach. I will update my answer to include the working code.

Comment: @CodeBender You haven't posted an answer. And do not update your question with working code. Post an actual answer if you want. Keep questions and answer separate.

Answer (score 6):

This is the working code derived from the answer provided by rmaddy above.

A few highlights:

1. Convert MyClass to MyStruct
2. Removed NSCoder inheritance from the object I wished to save
3. Removed calls to `NSKeyedArchiver` & `NSKeyedUnarchiver`
4. No longer saving to `UserDefaults`
5. Relying on `JSONEncoder` & `JSONDecoder` to write out struct
6. Writing to file system now as a `Data` object

This is the updated struct & enum that I wish to save:

```
enum Binary: Int {
    case a = 0
    case b = 1
    case c = 9
}

struct MyStruct {
    var string: String?
    var date: Date?
    var binary: Binary = .c

    init() { }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case string, date, binary
    }
}

extension MyStruct: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        string = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .string)
        date = try values.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        binary = try Binary(rawValue: values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .binary)) ?? .c
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(string, forKey: .string)
        try container.encode(date, forKey: .date)
        try container.encode(binary.rawValue, forKey: .binary)
    }
}
```

The updated controller class that handles reading & writing the output. In my case, writing out to JSON was fine, so I went with that approach.

```
class MyStructController {
    private var myStruct: MyStruct

    init() {
        self.myStruct = MyStruct()
        self.myStruct.string = "string"
        self.myStruct.date = Date()
        self.myStruct.binary = .a
    }

    func writeMyStruct() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(myStruct)
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                appropriateFor:nil,
                                                                create:false)
            let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: MyStruct.self))
            try data.write(to: url)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func readMyStruct() {
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                appropriateFor:nil,
                                                                create:false)
            let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: MyStruct.self))
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let myNewStruct = try decoder.decode(MyStruct.self, from: data)
            print("string: \(myNewStruct.string ?? "nil") date: \(myNewStruct.date ?? Date()) binary: \(myNewStruct.binary)")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @CodeBender works just fine, though **there is no need to do manual encoding / decoding** using `init(from decoder: Decoder)` and `encode(to encoder: Encoder)` methods, doing so just defeats the very purpose of the GREAT **Codable** protocol, unless you need to do some complex level of encoding / decoding.

Here is the code that works just well using the pure benefit of Codable protocol:

```
import UIKit

struct Movie: Codable {

    enum MovieGenere: String, Codable {
        case horror, drama, comedy, adventure, animation
    }

    var name : String
    var moviesGenere : [MovieGenere]
    var rating : Int
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        writeMyMovie(movie: Movie(name: "Titanic", moviesGenere: [Movie.MovieGenere.drama], rating: 1))

        readMyMovie()
    }

    var documentDirectoryURL:URL? {
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                appropriateFor:nil,
                                                                create:false)
            return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: Movie.self))
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func writeMyMovie(movie:Movie) {

        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(movie)
            try data.write(to: documentDirectoryURL!) // CAN USE GUARD STATEMENT HERE TO CHECK VALID URL INSTEAD OF FORCE UNWRAPPING, IN MY CASE AM 100% SURE, HENCE NOT GUARDING ;)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func readMyMovie() {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: documentDirectoryURL!)
            let movie = try JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
            print("MOVIE DECODED: \(movie.name)")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```